# creating a list containing list of employees

Tags: python, list

I need to create a program that contains a list of employees in a company. The program should allow for the addition of employees to the list as they join the company. When an employee leaves the company, the program should find their index number in the list and replace their name with the name of a new employee.

this is what I've done so far, i think it's nearly finished, could someone help me finish it please??

```
 def main():

     #create list
     employee = ["Ciara Murphy", "Shauna Williams", "Sarah Kelly", "Evana Leanne"]

     #print list
     print(employee)

     #print item at line index 2
     print(employee[2])

     #insert at index 3
     employee.insert(3, "Alana Marie")
     print(employee[3])

     #try
     print(employee.index("Sarah Kelly"))

 main()
```

I'm using python 3.3.2

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? What is your problem?

Comment: What if there's no new employee to replace them?  What if the company roster just goes down by one?  This seems like a good time for a class or two: Employee and Company come to mind.  Encapsulate that logic.

Comment: @duffymo I personally doubt he knows the use of classes.

Comment: What are you nearly finished? Are you learning Python? If yes, you should learn the basics from documentation and tutorial at first.

Comment: @alKid - you're probably right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed the whole point of the program.

A program that allows such things like printing, and adding should have methods available that do that.

Your program does allow anything, the person that uses the program has no control over what is being done.

Let's say you are a person that wants to use this program. The program should have a menu at the start telling what the person can do to add, print and replace people in the list.

So the program should have a loop, and do things according to user input. To get user input use

```
answer = input("")
```

Here is pseudocode of how this should look like:

```
workers = []
def main():
    while True:
        answer = input("What would you like to do?")
        if answer == "p":
            printAllWorkers()
        elif answer == "a":
            addWorker()
        elif answer == "q":
            return
```

You will then put the logic of the program inside the functions.